# magento offline orders and payment later

Tags: php

I have a website that handles Whole-sellers.

our business process

```
1) whole-sellers need to place an order without doing any payment. 
2) Then email will send to the admin and the manufacturer about the order
3) After manufacturing process is completed manufacturer is informing that is completed
4) then we need to inform to our customer and collect the payment from the customer via online payment method.
```

My question is can we have this kind of a process in Magento. by placing orders without any payment and after that requesting the payment to done through the website.

Comment: not in a default Magento Setup..

Comment: @Dexter cant we invoice later?

Comment: yes you can invoice later if its an offline payment. But there is no option to make the online payment later after order is placed.

Comment: @Dexter yes bro that is the issue.

Comment: then you follow create create shipment then after getting payment create invoice......In magento in voice means order payment is done